# Forcetype Expressions doesn't work for jooq version 3.10

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using a custom converter and using the following expression in the forceType. But it looks the the expression doesnt work and the converter doesnt get executed.

```xml
<forcedType>
        <name>UPOrigin</name>
        <expression>up_entries\.origin|up_methods\.origin</expression>
</forcedType>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Until version 3.11, you have to either *fully* qualify your expressions (including schema name) or leave them unqualified. I've created a feature request to improve this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7947

In jOOQ 3.11, any of these should work:

#### Using an explicit schema name:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>UPOrigin</name>
    <expression>my_schema\.(up_entries\.origin|up_methods\.origin)</expression>
</forcedType>
```

#### Matching all schemas:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>UPOrigin</name>
    <expression>.*?\.(up_entries\.origin|up_methods\.origin)</expression>
</forcedType>
```

#### Using unqualified column names:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>UPOrigin</name>
    <expression>origin</expression>
</forcedType>
```